# How to save custom attribute in Magento module

Tags: product, module, event-observer

I have this hidden input that I am submitting along with my checkout form:

```
<input id="text_value" type="hidden" value="This is a test Value" name="text_value"></input>
```

I was wondering How I could save this value to my custom attribute field I have saved in Magento. I already have the attribute created in the attribute tables, and I already created some columns for the attribute in the quote_item table, the order table, and a couple others. Using this code, and observer I am able to save the entered text to the quote_item table, but I'm unable to fetch any values from the product page itself when they add an item to the cart

Config observer:

```
<sales_quote_item_set_product>
    <observers>
        <m_p>
            <class>m_p_Model_Observer_Quote</class>
            <method>salesQuoteOptions</method>
        </m_p>
    </observers>
</sales_quote_item_set_product>
```

Observer function contents:

```
$quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem();
$product = $observer->getProduct();
$quoteItem->setMuProductembroideryOptions('TEST VALUE');
```

Using the above code I was able to save "TEST VALUE" to my custom attribute column in the quote_item table when I clicked the add to cart button. I would like to do this exact thing but using the hidden input box as my value. I already tried fetching the post request and looking for "text_value" in the request, but nothing comes up. Any help would be great

Comment: How exactly are you trying to access the post request?

Comment: Using: Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('paramname') I figured out that i was just calling the wrong event to observe, i will be posting an answer with the correct event